# how to pass elemnts to a div

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass this element to another active div when i click on the cart i made an e-commerce website

**HTML the cart div is active and the cart the box is addto**

```
<div class="active"> 
                <div class="text">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-x xmark"></i>
                </div>
            </div> // this is the cart
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/products/f1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>T-shirt</h1>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping addto"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col1">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="img/products/f1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>T-shirt2</h1>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping addto"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let cartPage = document.querySelector(".active");
let xMark = document.querySelector(".xmark");
let col1 = document.getElementsByClassName("col1")
let addTo = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("addto"));

cart.addEventListener("click",function(){
    cartPage.style.width = "30%";
    cartPage.style.opacity = "1";
    cartPage.style.zIndex = "10";

});
xMark.addEventListener("click",function (){
    cartPage.style.width = "0";
    cartPage.style.opacity = "0";
    cartPage.style.zIndex = "-1";
    
});
```

i need when i click on addto variable i need to append the col1 to the cartPage

Comment: but addto class is not visible in this case.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to physically move the div and all its contents to also be nested inside of the div that has the `.active` class on it? Can you show an example of what your expected outcome should be?

Comment: yes i need to move the div and all it contains  to the .active